# I want to access Excel file from download folder in Android in My app which support Andorid 5 to 12. Google rejected App, I using READ_EXTREAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, kotlin, local-storage, android-download-manager, runtime-permissions

My app rejected by google.
I am using READ_EXTREAL_STORAGE OR ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION OR ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION.
I want to access only *.xls files from Download folder in my app.
And then app will ready excel data.

Is there any universal simplest solution?

Thank you

Comment: Use the [storage access framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#overview) to let your users pick the file to read.

Comment: You need READ_EXTREAL_STORAGE only.